# I am using Python, Pyspark package, to count the words in a very large text file of data

Tags: python-3.x

Right now, I have the code, but the code keeps breaking. The error message that I am getting is py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o43.saveAsTextFile.

```
 import sys
 import os
 import pandas as pd
 from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
 from operator import add
 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
 from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
 sc=SparkContext()
 sc.setLogLevel("Error")
 a=sc.textFile("F:/part=r-0000")
 b=a.flatMap(lambda x:x.split()).map(lambda x:(x,1)).reduceByKey(lambda 
 a,b:a+b)
 b.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("F:word-count2.txt")
```